# jQuery Timetable Widget required

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-plugins

I am looking for advice or examples of how to create a timetable widget as shown in the image below;

[image: Timetable design]

I need the user to be able to **drag** the rectangles to **move** or **resize** them up and down each column of the timetable.

It's quite simple when you look at it but I imagine the JavaScript involved is quite tricky and I just don't know where to start.

I'm thinking of using a table and overlaying div's but that's about as far as I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, how about using the [jQuery Fullcalendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)? Just use the week view.

[image: fullcalendar screenshot]

Comment: This is what I actually am using now, the "week view" but I'm finding it very buggy and the amount of bugs I'm coming across makes me think I should just write my own and avoid the bloat.

Comment: @Matt Ball - is there any way to remove the dates? Like I just want to display Sunday, Monday, Tuesday and etc.

Comment: @chobo2 http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?

A quick look on google finds this [scheduler](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/)

If you dont end up using it it should at least help with where to start.

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, which is why I asked for a timetable widget.  I'd already had a quick look on Google (obviously, I don't ask questions for fun) and found the one you have suggested in your answer but it's too heavy for what I require.